# Ranking of Go Software

Tags: go, computer-ai, rank

Where could I find information about the level of Go playing software? In particular, I am looking for commercial software.

Ideally, I'd like to find a live ranking, as obviously this field is evolving fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, AlphaGo is the top AI now. Besides it, a simple way to find information about Computer Go Ranking would be to search for :

> Computer go tournament

Here is a list of [Go AI from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Go#List_of_Go-playing_computer_programs)

There's a special website called [Computer GO](http://www.computer-go.info/) that registers past and future tournaments.

There's also a website for [KGS Computer Tournaments](http://www.weddslist.com/kgs/)

According to the [KGS tournament](http://www.weddslist.com/kgs/annual/index.html), the actual ranking is :

1. Zen
2. DolBaram
3. abakus
4. Darkforest
5. Hira
6. Aya

As for commercial AIs, I don't think their level match the ones quoted here. It would require much hardware resources to run on a smartphone or a personnal computer.

Comment: Great tip about the computer go website! There's actually an important tournament this week: http://jsb.cs.uec.ac.jp/~igo/eng/participant.html

Comment: Zen won the 4th Densei Cup on March 20, and won a 3 stone handicap game against Kobayashi Koichi 9P on March 23.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the strongest programs, like CrazyStone and Zen, have now reached the top 100 on KGS, [their current KGS ranking is available on this page](https://www.gokgs.com/top100.jsp).

Sensei's library has a page dedicated to [KGS bot rating](http://senseis.xmp.net/?KGSBotRatings), including highest rank, historical rating and current rating.

As of March 2016, CrazyStone and Zen19X are KGS 7d, Hira is KGS 5d. [According to his author](http://www.remi-coulom.fr/CrazyStone/), CrazyStone has become considerably stronger thanks to deep learning.

Live charts:
[CrazyStone](https://www.gokgs.com/graphPage.jsp?user=CrazyStone) -
[Zen19X](https://www.gokgs.com/graphPage.jsp?user=Zen19X) -
[DolBaram](https://www.gokgs.com/graphPage.jsp?user=DolBaram) -
[Hira](https://www.gokgs.com/graphPage.jsp?user=HiraBot)